# No leading zero in hour using scale_x_datetime

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

Is it possible to strip the leading zero from the hour as displayed on the x axis, while using ggplot2's scale_x_datetime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `date_format` from `scales` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

# dummy data
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
  x = as.POSIXct(runif(10, 0, 24 * 60 * 60), origin = "2017/04/20"),
  y = 1:10
)

# use scales::date_format
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%l:%M"))
```

[?strptime](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html):

> `%k` The 24-hour clock time with single digits preceded by a blank.
>   `%l` The 12-hour clock time with single digits preceded by a blank.

[image]